# Why is my post.req not posting to mongodb?

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I'm trying to create a registration form for my application and am successfully posting data to my local mongoDB, but not my cloud db. When I open my live Heroku site, an application error occurs after submitting the registration form data. I've created a connection to my local DB, as well as a connection to the cloud DB by using process.env variables. The connection to the cloud DB is successful, but the registration POST data is not. Here's my db connection:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var ServerApiVersion = require('mongodb');
var dbURI = 'mongodb://localhost:27017/Dropship_site';

if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production'){
    dbURI = process.env.MONGODB_URI;
} 

mongoose.connect(dbURI, {
    useNewUrlParser: true,
    useUnifiedTopology: true,
    serverApi: ServerApiVersion.v1
});

/* Event Listeners */
mongoose.connection.on('connected', function(){
    console.log('Mongoose connected to ' + dbURI + ' & NODE_ENV is ' + process.env.NODE_ENV);
});

mongoose.connection.on('error', function(err){
    console.log("Mongoose error: " + err);
});

mongoose.connection.on('disconnected', function(){
    console.log('Mongoose disconnected');
});

// Close connection to database, display mesage as to why the connection was closed,
// and call callback to terminate the process manually
var gracefulShutdown = function(msg, callback){
    mongoose.connection.close(function(){
        console.log('Mongoose disconnected from ' + msg);
        callback();
    });
};


// Event emmited on app termination locally
process.on('SIGINT', function(){
    gracefulShutdown('app termination', function(){
        process.exit(0);
    });
});

// Event emmited on app shutdown via heroku
process.on('SIGTERM', function(){
    gracefulShutdown('Heroku app shutdown', function(){
        process.exit(0);
    });
});

// Require schemas

require('./User');
```

my User Schema:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose')
const Schema = mongoose.Schema

const userSchema = new Schema({
    username: {
        type: String
    },
    email: {
        type: String
    },
    password: {
        type: String
    }
}, {timestamps: true})

const User = mongoose.model('User', userSchema)
module.exports = User
```

My registration controller:

```
const register = (req, res, next) => {
    bcrypt.hash(req.body.password, 10, function(err, hashedPass) {
        if(err) {
            res.json({
                error: "error"
            })
        }

        let user = new User({
        username: req.body.username,
        email: req.body.email,
        password: hashedPass 
        })

        var errorcheck = req.body;
        console.log(JSON.stringify(errorcheck));

        user.save()
        .then(user => {
            // res.json({
            //  message: 'User saved successfully!'
            // })
            return res.redirect('/');
        })
        .catch(error => {
            res.json({
                message: 'An Error occurred!'
            })
        })
    })
}
```

And my registration form in jade:

```
  form.modal-content.animate(action='/api/register' method='post')
    .imgcontainer
      span.close(onclick="document.getElementById('id02').style.display='none'" title='Close Modal') ×
    .container
      label(for='username')
        b Username
      input(type='text' placeholder='Enter username' name='username' required='true')
      label(for='email')
        b Email
      input(type='text' placeholder='Enter your email' name='email' required='true')
      label(for='password')
        b Password
      input(type='password' placeholder='Enter new password' name='password' required='true')
      button(type='submit') Register
      label
        input(type='checkbox' checked='checked' name='remember')
        |  Remember me
    .container(style='background-color:#f1f1f1')
      button.cancelbtn(type='button' onclick="document.getElementById('id02').style.display='none'") Cancel
      span.psw
        | Forgot 
        a(href='#') password?
```

I'm really bad at debugging, so I'll post the whole Heroku logs below:

```
2022-10-14T16:26:37.273097+00:00 app[web.1]: type: 'Unknown',
2022-10-14T16:26:37.273097+00:00 app[web.1]: hosts: [],
2022-10-14T16:26:37.273098+00:00 app[web.1]: passives: [],
2022-10-14T16:26:37.273098+00:00 app[web.1]: arbiters: [],
2022-10-14T16:26:37.273098+00:00 app[web.1]: tags: {},
2022-10-14T16:26:37.273098+00:00 app[web.1]: minWireVersion: 0,
2022-10-14T16:26:37.273098+00:00 app[web.1]: maxWireVersion: 0,
2022-10-14T16:26:37.273098+00:00 app[web.1]: roundTripTime: -1,
2022-10-14T16:26:37.273098+00:00 app[web.1]: lastUpdateTime: 2797196129,
2022-10-14T16:26:37.273099+00:00 app[web.1]: lastWriteDate: 0,
2022-10-14T16:26:37.273099+00:00 app[web.1]: error: MongoNetworkError: connection <monitor> to 52.3.191.81:27017 closed
2022-10-14T16:26:37.273099+00:00 app[web.1]: at Connection.onClose (/app/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb/lib/cmap/connection.js:135:19)
2022-10-14T16:26:37.273100+00:00 app[web.1]: at TLSSocket.<anonymous> (/app/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb/lib/cmap/connection.js:62:46)
2022-10-14T16:26:37.273100+00:00 app[web.1]: at TLSSocket.emit (node:events:513:28)
2022-10-14T16:26:37.273100+00:00 app[web.1]: at node:net:301:12
2022-10-14T16:26:37.273100+00:00 app[web.1]: at TCP.done (node:_tls_wrap:588:7) {
2022-10-14T16:26:37.273100+00:00 app[web.1]: [Symbol(errorLabels)]: Set(0) {}
2022-10-14T16:26:37.273101+00:00 app[web.1]: },
2022-10-14T16:26:37.273101+00:00 app[web.1]: topologyVersion: null,
2022-10-14T16:26:37.273101+00:00 app[web.1]: setName: null,
2022-10-14T16:26:37.273101+00:00 app[web.1]: setVersion: null,
2022-10-14T16:26:37.273101+00:00 app[web.1]: electionId: null,
2022-10-14T16:26:37.273101+00:00 app[web.1]: logicalSessionTimeoutMinutes: null,
2022-10-14T16:26:37.273101+00:00 app[web.1]: primary: null,
2022-10-14T16:26:37.273102+00:00 app[web.1]: me: null,
2022-10-14T16:26:37.273102+00:00 app[web.1]: '$clusterTime': null
2022-10-14T16:26:37.273103+00:00 app[web.1]: },
2022-10-14T16:26:37.273103+00:00 app[web.1]: 'ac-h6dahg4-shard-00-02.qvdngap.mongodb.net:27017' => ServerDescription {
2022-10-14T16:26:37.273103+00:00 app[web.1]: address: 'ac-h6dahg4-shard-00-02.qvdngap.mongodb.net:27017',
2022-10-14T16:26:37.273103+00:00 app[web.1]: type: 'Unknown',
2022-10-14T16:26:37.273103+00:00 app[web.1]: hosts: [],
2022-10-14T16:26:37.273103+00:00 app[web.1]: passives: [],
2022-10-14T16:26:37.273103+00:00 app[web.1]: arbiters: [],
2022-10-14T16:26:37.273104+00:00 app[web.1]: tags: {},
2022-10-14T16:26:37.273104+00:00 app[web.1]: minWireVersion: 0,
2022-10-14T16:26:37.273104+00:00 app[web.1]: maxWireVersion: 0,
2022-10-14T16:26:37.273104+00:00 app[web.1]: roundTripTime: -1,
2022-10-14T16:26:37.273104+00:00 app[web.1]: lastUpdateTime: 2797196347,
2022-10-14T16:26:37.273104+00:00 app[web.1]: lastWriteDate: 0,
2022-10-14T16:26:37.273104+00:00 app[web.1]: error: MongoNetworkError: connection <monitor> to 52.6.243.110:27017 closed
2022-10-14T16:26:37.273105+00:00 app[web.1]: at Connection.onClose (/app/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb/lib/cmap/connection.js:135:19)
2022-10-14T16:26:37.273105+00:00 app[web.1]: at TLSSocket.<anonymous> (/app/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb/lib/cmap/connection.js:62:46)
2022-10-14T16:26:37.273105+00:00 app[web.1]: at TLSSocket.emit (node:events:513:28)
2022-10-14T16:26:37.273105+00:00 app[web.1]: at node:net:301:12
2022-10-14T16:26:37.273116+00:00 app[web.1]: at TCP.done (node:_tls_wrap:588:7) {
2022-10-14T16:26:37.273116+00:00 app[web.1]: [Symbol(errorLabels)]: Set(0) {}
2022-10-14T16:26:37.273117+00:00 app[web.1]: },
2022-10-14T16:26:37.273117+00:00 app[web.1]: topologyVersion: null,
2022-10-14T16:26:37.273117+00:00 app[web.1]: setName: null,
2022-10-14T16:26:37.273117+00:00 app[web.1]: setVersion: null,
2022-10-14T16:26:37.273117+00:00 app[web.1]: electionId: null,
2022-10-14T16:26:37.273117+00:00 app[web.1]: logicalSessionTimeoutMinutes: null,
2022-10-14T16:26:37.273117+00:00 app[web.1]: primary: null,
2022-10-14T16:26:37.273118+00:00 app[web.1]: me: null,
2022-10-14T16:26:37.273118+00:00 app[web.1]: '$clusterTime': null
2022-10-14T16:26:37.273118+00:00 app[web.1]: },
2022-10-14T16:26:37.273118+00:00 app[web.1]: 'ac-h6dahg4-shard-00-00.qvdngap.mongodb.net:27017' => ServerDescription {
2022-10-14T16:26:37.273118+00:00 app[web.1]: address: 'ac-h6dahg4-shard-00-00.qvdngap.mongodb.net:27017',
2022-10-14T16:26:37.273118+00:00 app[web.1]: type: 'Unknown',
2022-10-14T16:26:37.273119+00:00 app[web.1]: hosts: [],
2022-10-14T16:26:37.273119+00:00 app[web.1]: passives: [],
2022-10-14T16:26:37.273119+00:00 app[web.1]: arbiters: [],
2022-10-14T16:26:37.273119+00:00 app[web.1]: tags: {},
2022-10-14T16:26:37.273123+00:00 app[web.1]: minWireVersion: 0,
2022-10-14T16:26:37.273124+00:00 app[web.1]: maxWireVersion: 0,
2022-10-14T16:26:37.273124+00:00 app[web.1]: roundTripTime: -1,
2022-10-14T16:26:37.273124+00:00 app[web.1]: lastUpdateTime: 2797196364,
2022-10-14T16:26:37.273124+00:00 app[web.1]: lastWriteDate: 0,
2022-10-14T16:26:37.273124+00:00 app[web.1]: error: MongoNetworkError: connection <monitor> to 52.45.16.161:27017 closed
2022-10-14T16:26:37.273129+00:00 app[web.1]: at Connection.onClose (/app/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb/lib/cmap/connection.js:135:19)
2022-10-14T16:26:37.273129+00:00 app[web.1]: at TLSSocket.<anonymous> (/app/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb/lib/cmap/connection.js:62:46)
2022-10-14T16:26:37.273129+00:00 app[web.1]: at TLSSocket.emit (node:events:513:28)
2022-10-14T16:26:37.273129+00:00 app[web.1]: at node:net:301:12
2022-10-14T16:26:37.273130+00:00 app[web.1]: at TCP.done (node:_tls_wrap:588:7) {
2022-10-14T16:26:37.273130+00:00 app[web.1]: [Symbol(errorLabels)]: Set(0) {}
2022-10-14T16:26:37.273130+00:00 app[web.1]: },
2022-10-14T16:26:37.273130+00:00 app[web.1]: topologyVersion: null,
2022-10-14T16:26:37.273130+00:00 app[web.1]: setName: null,
2022-10-14T16:26:37.273131+00:00 app[web.1]: setVersion: null,
2022-10-14T16:26:37.273131+00:00 app[web.1]: electionId: null,
2022-10-14T16:26:37.273131+00:00 app[web.1]: logicalSessionTimeoutMinutes: null,
2022-10-14T16:26:37.273131+00:00 app[web.1]: primary: null,
2022-10-14T16:26:37.273131+00:00 app[web.1]: me: null,
2022-10-14T16:26:37.273131+00:00 app[web.1]: '$clusterTime': null
2022-10-14T16:26:37.273132+00:00 app[web.1]: }
2022-10-14T16:26:37.273132+00:00 app[web.1]: },
2022-10-14T16:26:37.273132+00:00 app[web.1]: stale: false,
2022-10-14T16:26:37.273132+00:00 app[web.1]: compatible: true,
2022-10-14T16:26:37.273133+00:00 app[web.1]: heartbeatFrequencyMS: 10000,
2022-10-14T16:26:37.273133+00:00 app[web.1]: localThresholdMS: 15,
2022-10-14T16:26:37.273133+00:00 app[web.1]: setName: 'atlas-40g85t-shard-0',
2022-10-14T16:26:37.273133+00:00 app[web.1]: maxElectionId: null,
2022-10-14T16:26:37.273133+00:00 app[web.1]: maxSetVersion: null,
2022-10-14T16:26:37.273134+00:00 app[web.1]: commonWireVersion: 0,
2022-10-14T16:26:37.273134+00:00 app[web.1]: logicalSessionTimeoutMinutes: null
2022-10-14T16:26:37.273134+00:00 app[web.1]: },
2022-10-14T16:26:37.273134+00:00 app[web.1]: code: undefined
2022-10-14T16:26:37.273134+00:00 app[web.1]: }
2022-10-14T16:26:37.420404+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2022-10-14T16:26:37.632701+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from up to crashed
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: "_an application error occurs after submitting the registration form data_" - what error? Can you post the specific one that is being thrown?

Comment: "I've added the heroku logs after submitting the form data. Sorry I couldn't narrow it down, I just couldn't find the specific error

Comment: Thanks! `error: MongoNetworkError: connection <monitor> to 52.3.191.81:27017 closed`. How are you confirming that the connection is successful? Have you added the Heroku IP address to the access list for the Atlas cluster? Searching that error message (minus the IP) surfaces a variety of potential leads

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).